# error: " SyntaxError: Quantificateur *incorrect. " (french terms)

Tags: google-apps-script, syntax-error

I use my google scripts without problems until this morning...
All my scripts were good and worked.
And this morning, after I used after 5 or 6 times my scripts, a google message appeared:(background red with white text in a little banner)

> " 'SyntaxError:Quantificateur* incorrect . Ignorer'"

So, The translation should be:

> "'SyntaxError:Quantifier* incorrect . Ignore'"

No changes in my scripts... yesterday everything worked well.

I can not find explanations about this google message online..
So, Do you know what's wrong ???

Comment: Could you share example of the code?

Comment: Your error is originated by wrong usage of Regex